# How to make a consistent splash screen in android hybrid app?

Tags: android, splash-screen, hybrid

I've splash screen in my application which appears to be working fine. Once the html is loaded the splash screen goes off. Since the html page takes time to load it showed a blank screen. To cope up with the splash screen, I again added the same image into my html and display it to the user till the page is completely loaded. 
   Everything is working fine, except that there is a flickering when the view-port shifts from splash to html image. The problem is when the splash screen is displayed the image seems to be zoomed in and when the html displays the splash it is zoomed out(shows full size). How to maintain a consistency among the splash screen and the image in html?

Comment: please put your code first...!!!

Comment: There is nothing to provide. I'm using phonegap. It is giving some splash screen. It loads my html page and turns off the splash screen. In my page it takes time to load the content. To wrap up the gap i'm using the same image as background of body. Even though it is same, i can see some changes in the view. i hope you got it..